# java - copy specific rows from a file to another file

Tags: java, file, copy

I have a file with the following format:

```
.ID 1
.Customers
A customer
One girl
.Products
Milk
Oil
Silk
.Date
12-1-2000
.ID2
.Customers
Anna Tall
.Products
Hairspray
.Date
21-5-2001
.ID 3
.Customers
Jane Eldest
Tom Ford
.Products
Shampoo
```

etc.

I would like to make different files, named for exaple 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt etc, in which files I want to have the following lines: .Customers(lines of customers) .Date(line of date), or if .Date does not exist, only .Customers. Each line starting with .ID determines a different new file. How could I do that? Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried? What OS are you on? This does not sound like something for which you need Java if you have scripting tools (awk, Perl) available.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am using Netbeans IDE 8.0 .

Comment: The IDE is used to type Java code. Whether you type your Java code with NetBeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ, Notepad or vi is irrelevant. Java code is Java code. Google for "Java IO tutorial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an skeleton so you can continue yourself:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file"));
        String line;
        State state = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith(".")) {
                // detect state
            } else {
                // handle data for state
            }
        }
    }

    static enum State {
        CUSTOMER, PRODUCTS, STATE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I can handle it now :D